# How to use compression while saving pdf file using PDFView4Net component

Tags: wpf, pdf-generation

I need to compress the pdf file while saving, through PDFView4Net component using WPF.

Comment: Have you checked with the vendor if they support this?

Comment: It looks like PDF4Net library of the same vendor compress the document but PDFView4Net does not.